# Unable to close materialize css featureDiscovery circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

Using the next.materializecss.com featureDiscovery feature.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tap-target').featureDiscovery();
    $('.tap-target').featureDiscovery('open');
  });
  function closeFeatureDiscovery() {
    $('.tap-target').featureDiscovery('close');
  }
</script>
```

When the page loads, it opens, but throws this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
```

I have a button within the circle that says "I understand" and want it to trigger the feature to close. Using their code (as seen above) just throws the same error as the open:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined
```

[Their example](http://next.materializecss.com/feature-discovery.html) uses the same version of jQuery (3.2.1).

The feature does close if you click ANYWHERE other than within the circle, but I'm unable to get it to trigger with the button within.

I'm able to hack it closed by just having my button remove the 'open' class. This would work, but it also leaves some kind of listener that catches all clicks on the page, so if I want to do something on the page, I have to click once to get rid of their trigger, then click again to do it.

```
<div id="feature-discovery-view-event" class="tap-target red" data-target="btn-view-event">
    <div class="tap-target-content">
        <h5>View your Item</h5>
        <p>
            Click this button at any time to view your item.<br>
            <a class="btn" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="closeFeatureDiscovery();">I understand.</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML code ...

Comment: I've added the html.

Comment: try looking into this http://materializecss.com/feature-discovery.html

Comment: They use `data-activates` instead of `data-target` then `$('.tap-target').featureDiscovery('open');` and `$('.tap-target').featureDiscovery('close`);` for opening and closing

Comment: @CodeLover the example you're using is from materialize.css, not next.materialize.css

Comment: But have you tried it?

Comment: @CodeLover have I tried what? changing the target? That part works just fine.  It's the close part that doesn't work (which is identical in your suggestion)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if still interested, but try this one with your solution.

(Version of materializecss I use works with tapTarget method).

Call close and **destroy** which might remove the event handlers.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tap-target').tapTarget();
    $('.tap-target').tapTarget('open');
  });
  function closeFeatureDiscovery() {
    $('.tap-target').tapTarget('close');
    $('.tap-target').tapTarget('destroy');
  }
</script>
```